# Foundation5 Tabs - Uncaught Error Type?

Tags: html, wordpress, tabs, zurb-foundation

Good day all, I hope everybody is well.

I am having some troubles executing Foundation 5 Tabs to my site. 
I came cross this: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/856-foundation-5-tab-issues and found similar output, just that mine are not working.

It seems that something blocked my script. I tried to moved it to my header.php, different parts of footer.php, and single.php, but no luck.

Images of output can be seen at the bottom.

Hope someone can help me out with this.

```
<?php /* single.php */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<body>



<section class="common-title-wrap">

    <div class="row"><h2><?php single_post_title(); ?></h2></div>    

</section>



<section class="common-section">

    <div class="single-column">
        <div class="side-nav">
             <?php

             $options = array(

             'sort_column' => 'menu_order',

             'menu' => 'Equipment Menu',

             'container' => false

             );

            wp_nav_menu($options); ?>


        </div>

        <div class="tab-column">
<ul class="tabs" data-tab role="tablist">
  <li class="tab-title active" role="presentation"><a href="#panel2-1" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="panel2-1">Equipment</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title" role="presentation"><a href="#panel2-2" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="panel2-2">Equipment Rental</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title" role="presentation"><a href="#panel2-3" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="panel2-3">Equipment Purchase</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title" role="presentation"><a href="#panel2-4" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="panel2-4">Video<a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content">
  <section role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" class="content active" id="panel2-1">
    <p><?php echo the_field('equipment'); ?></p>
  </section>
  <section role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="content" id="panel2-2">
    <p><?php echo the_field('equipment_rental'); ?></p>
  </section>
  <section role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="content" id="panel2-3">
    <p><?php echo the_field('equipment_purchase'); ?></p>
  </section>
  <section role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="content" id="panel2-4">
    <p><?php echo the_field('equipment_video'); ?></p>
  </section>
        </div>  
    </div>

</div>


</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

```
<?php /* Template Name: Footer */ ?>

<footer>

       <div class="site-footer">

            <div class="copyright">

                <p>Copyright ©.  All Rights Reserved.</p>

            </div>

        </div>
</footer>


<?php wp_footer();?>

  <script src="/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

  <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.tab.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
      });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).foundation();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Output Screenshots]

Comment: Well those definitely aren't the correct paths to your scripts...I highly recommend learning to use `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your script locations aren't pointing correctly.  When you run scripts using that format "/js/something.js", you're telling the server to go to the root folder, find the 'js' folder and then run the file you've specified.  With your WordPress install, this is in domain.com/js/something.js, *not* in wordpress.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/js/something.js where everything is referenced through.

You need to do 1 of 3 things:

1. Move your JS files to the actual root of the domain in a folder called 'JS'.  I don't really recommend this solution as you're then separating your JS from your theme and adding files to the root, but this would fix your problem easily.
2. Use the built-in WP functions like get_template_directory(), get_stylesheet_directory(), and other similar functions.  With these, you can make your paths look like `<script src="<?php get_theme_directory(); ?>/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>` and it'll point to the right spot.  Look at the WP documentation and find the one appropriate for your situation.
3. Use the wp_enqueue_scripts() functions and features to load your scripts.  This is the best way to do this and is the way you *should* be handling this.  The benefit of this method is that WP will watch for scripts so none of them load multiple times (unnecessarily) and it'll ensure that dependencies for scripts are met (foundation.js loads after jquery.js and any plugin JS, etc.).  This is the most difficult method, but it's not really that hard and you really **have** to know how to do this if you're going to be developing WP themes.

Good luck!

Comment: Anyone care to explain why this is being downvoted? It's the correct answer to the question posted... :-/